# NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE being sent all the time by IE8 on Windows XP SP3

Tags: ajax, post, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, windows-xp-sp3

I currently have Apache setup using the mod_spnego module to do Kerberos based Windows Authentication in the browser to enable Single Sign-On.  The module I'm using is available here:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

Because IE has a habit of sending the NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE request every time after an authentication is done (which I don't want), it will wipe out the post arguments that have been sent from an AJAX request.

I have used the following registry option to sort this problem out on all other client machines:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251404

However, this does not have any affect in Windows XP (SP3) with IE8.

Any idea on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.